# Determining which key is pressed and saving to database

Tags: php, javascript, database

I have a code which is helping for determining which key is pressed. But I confused, I do not know how can I save this key -(button) is pressed-. Is this possible? Can I use php codes in javascript to create a new line in my mysql database?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function textsizer(e) {
        var evtobj = window.event ? event : e;
        var unicode = evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode;
        var actualkey = String.fromCharCode(unicode);
        if (actualkey == "a") {
            //database code needed
        }
    }
    document.onkeypress = textsizer;
</script>
```

Comment: This question is too broad. Please post some code and specify your question.

Comment: can you share some part of your code?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">`
`function textsizer(e)`
`{`
`var evtobj=window.event? event : e`
`var unicode=evtobj.charCode? evtobj.charCode : evtobj.keyCode`
`var actualkey=String.fromCharCode(unicode)`
`if (actualkey=="a")`
`//database code needed`
`}`
`document.onkeypress=textsizer`
`</script>`

Comment: Post additional information that's requested in comments into the actual question (you can edit it) rather than as additional comments, that way all of the relevant information is kept together for future viewers.

Comment: do you want to save something when key "a" is pressed to database? you will need to make an ajax call and send data to php code on server..

Comment: @Amitd exactly! how can i find codes which are necessary for this?

Comment: @user1783032 see an example http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Comment: google - php ajax .. and you will find many good examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that JavaScript is a client-side language (it runs in the browser running on the user's computer) and PHP is a server-side language (it runs on your web server). You can't mix the two together because they run at different times.

What you could do is use is AJAX to send requests from your JavaScript code to your web server, without navigating away from the page, whenever a key is pressed. You'd simply send a key code (or the character that key code represents) as a parameter of the request, then your web server would handle saving that information to your database.

Comment: How can I use AJAX codes which are necessary for this connection? Is there any link or some keywords?

Comment: I can't speak to its quality, since I haven't read through all of it, but [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html) (from Google, so probably decent) would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that might help you get the ball rolling. I'm opting to use jquery, it will make this much more straight forward.

```
    window.bind('keydown', function(event){
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: 'http://asite.com/script_to_save_codes_to_db.php',
            data: event.keyCode,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data){
                //have the server respond with a boolean indicating that the keycode was saved to the db or not and decide what to do next
            }
        }
    );
});
```

How this works on the server side is a whole 'nother can of worms as it will depend on your server-side language and database choices.

For an entirely client-side solution you could save the keyCodes as a json string to localStorage or a cookie and do what you want with it later... But those can be wiped at any time and I would not call them databases.